# GNU Makefile dependency in multi-job make

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I have a c++ project under linux. I'm using GNU make and GCC

I have following rules:

```
all: ... 
version:
config:
  rm -f config.h
  @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory config.h
config.h:
 # ..... create the file config.h here
```

make version increases build number. 1.1-123, then 1.2-124 ... etc. The version is written in config.h file and config.h is included in all files in the project.

Now the idea is config.h to be rebuild in one of these cases:
  - when releasing a version of the program (rather than just developing/testing)
  - when it does not exists

so I do not want to make this dependancy:

```
all: config
config: version
```

because then config file will be rebuild on every make and every single file will be recompiled, not only changed files. So I want to not re-build config file while developing, but only if I do `make release_version`
Now. Lets say that rule is:

```
release_version: config version all
```

The problem is that when I do `make release_version -j 3` it'll make all the 3 targets (config, version, all) at the same time which means that version might not be ready for creation of config.h, then config.h might not be ready for `all`. So I must make this dependency:

release_version: all
all: config
config: version

**BUT ONLY** when `make release_version` is executed. if `make all` is executed I don't want to have these dependencies.

Maybe I need something like:

release_version: version_release config_release all_release

all_release: config
config_release: config
version_release: version

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are a bit haphazard.  It would be good if you re-read what you have and clarified it.  What does the `version` target do?  What is the relationship between `version` and `config`?  What is the relationship between this `release_version` which you don't show anywhere, and `config` and `version`?

If I understand correctly you want to have the `all` rule that will build the code using the existing version of `config.h` (creating it if it doesn't exist), and the `release_version` rule that will update `config.h`, then build the code as if it were `all`.  I'm not sure what `version` and `config` do.

You can do it like this, unless I'm missing something:

```
all: ...

release_version:
        @rm -f config.h
        @$(MAKE) config.h
        @$(MAKE) all

config.h:
        ...create config.h...

.PHONY: all release_version
```

There are lots of other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU-make you can use an order-only prerequisite to force rules to be run in a particular order withou forcing them to run if they aren't needed by something else:

```
all: ...other targets... | config
        ...actions...

release_version: config version all
```

Now if you do a `make all` it will just rebuild the other targets before the `|`.  If `config` is needed for some other reason, it will wait for it to be done before running `...actions...`.

This may not be enough, as those other targets may run before `config`.  If you need them to wait until after `config`, you need to add `| config` to their prerequisites as well.